# How doctrine increments a primary key?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I had a problem  with doctrine that I solved but I' like to know the reason  of the problem.
I was trying to insert  a new register but doctrine tried to insert an  id that already exists , every time  I tried the id that doctrine tried to insert was incremented by one ,I was try since the id increments to the first  id that doesn't exists on the table

```
        $result = $storage->executeSQL($query);

        $updated_answer = new SurveyDatabaseAnswer();
        if (!empty($result))
            $updated_answer->setId($result[0]);

        $updated_answer->setClient($client);
        $updated_answer->setSurvey($survey);
        $updated_answer->setAnswer($answer);
        empty($result) ? $storage->persist($updated_answer) : $storage->merge($updated_answer);
        $storage->flush();
```

How `doctrine's` id generator o whatever...  works in the way that caused my that problem??

Comment: That should be handled by the database, not by the code. Is your `id` column set as primary key and with auto increment?

Comment: do you delete rows in the meantime ?

Comment: yes the column is set as primary key with autoincrement, and I didn't delete rows at meantime